# Why defer behaves differently with variables defined in the surrounding function than named results?

Tags: go

The program below returns

```
<nil>
hello
```

I expected both to return "hello" but it's not the case. I've found that the behaviour is given as example in the language [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements).

> For instance, if the deferred function is a function literal and the surrounding function has named result parameters that are in scope within the literal, the deferred function may access and modify the result parameters before they are returned.

My question is: why does defer works differently with variables defined in the surrounding function than with named results? Isn't it just a closure executed before the surrounding function returns?

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println(up())
    fmt.Println(up2())

}

func up() error {
    var err error
    defer func() {
        err = errors.New("hello")
    }()
    return err
}

func up2() (err error) {
    defer func() {
        err = errors.New("hello")
    }()
    return err
}

func up3() error {
    var err error
    fn := func() {
        err = errors.New("hello")
    }
    fn()
    return err
}
```

Comment: Because the language spec says so? What is the question?

Comment: The quote you took from the spec lays it out, defer can only alter a return value for named result parameters. It works differently because that's how it was designed. It likely reduces bugs where you could accidentally alter your return values, and it may also be the simpler implementation as well.

Comment: @Volker is says ``For instance`` so to me it seems to imply there is some kind of rule that "named result parameters" are part of.

Comment: @JimB to me it looks like the opposite (i.e. increases the number of bugs) as I expected defer to work just like any closure executed before return( equivalent of ``func up3()error`` from my example.) After reading the specs I've found this exception though the text is confusing. ``For instance makes`` it sound like the behaviour follows a specific rule when in fact there is no rule and it's actually an exception specific to the `defer` statement.

Comment: @themihai: except that should not have ever caused any latent bugs, because it could never have worked in the first place. It's part of the spec for defer, so it can't really be an exception when it's always the case. I agree it can be confusing if you didn't read the spec and/or test it out, but the rule itself seems very clear.

Comment: @JimB `For instance` means  `as an example`. Can you point me to the specification paragraph that can be used to infer this example related to the named result parameters ?  The examples are supposed to be optional and further clarify the specification not to be part of the specification, right?

Comment: @themihai: that is a remnant of an older wording of that section, and it seems another sentence was interjected i there. It's adding more detail about when they are invoked and what their scope is. Yes, the wording could probably be improved, but the details are all there. This isn't the forum to debate whether the facts should have been placed before or after a "For instance,".

Comment: One thing that might be confusing you is that the last line of up2() does nothing (setting the return value to the return value), and the defer is altering the return value directly. Eg. see https://tour.golang.org/basics/7

Comment: @JamesAntill in the real program it was meant to be used as a clean up task and overwrite the error if it fails . See here a use case which may make more sense https://play.golang.org/p/6dwHrhdCdP . The fact that the behaviour is different when you don't use named result params seems just odd to me and is poorly documented(AFAIAC)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [spec says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements):

> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to the moment the surrounding function returns, either because the surrounding function executed a return statement, reached the end of its function body, or because the corresponding goroutine is panicking.

A key point is that the deferred function is executed after the return statement is executed.

The [spec also says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements):

> A "return" statement in a function F terminates the execution of F, and optionally provides one or more result values. Any functions deferred by F are executed before F returns to its caller.

The function `up` returns nil because the deferred function sets `err` after the return statement provides the function result.

The function `up2` overwrites the result value set by the return statement.

Comment: For some reasons I thought defer is executed just like a closure injected `return` (i.e. equivalent of `up3` from my example) not "after" the surrounding function  returns thus the whole confusion. I believe the wording could be improved to make this more clear.

Comment: @themihai: it's still not "after" it returns, though that's just a technicality. Just below that statement: `deferred functions are invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns`

Comment: I think the language in the spec can be improved by saying "A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to the moment the surrounding function _terminates_. "   The order of execution with this change in terminology is: function terminates, deferred functions execute, function returns.

Comment: @JimB I mean that after the surrounding function "executes". Initially I mistakenly  thought the execution is  `surrounding function -> defer -> return`  but now I found out it is a kind of  ``surrounding function -> return ->  defer -> return``  so the behaviour of the named params totally makes sense.

Comment: @themihai It's `surrounding function -> defer -> return`. The return statement is part of the surrounding function. The return statement causes the surrounding function to terminate and optionally provides results. The function returns after the function terminates and deferred functions are executed.  Setting return values is one of few situations where it's important to distinguish function termination from return.

Comment: @CeriseLimón that makes sense. It's just that you I can't emulate "terminate" in Go thus the reason why I used  `sf  -> return -> defer -> return`. Technically it should be  `sf  -> terminate -> defer -> return`.  Would you mind to file an issue on https://github.com/golang/go/issues/new ?  I believe your proposal to use `terminate` instead of `return` is great and has high chances to be merged.

Comment: Panic and reaching the end of the function body also cause the surrounding function to terminate.